# Is it there any way to force "Passwd" command to ask existing password everytime?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, passwords

Myself running Kali 2.0 Sana which was Debian based system. Currently running as `root` user.

One of the common problem I face was any user whom has physical access can change my `root` password within minutes.

The `passwd` command lets you do it without existing password, whenever the command gets executed without asking for existing password.

The `passwd` command was just a example, but there might be some hidden tricks to change password without root users existing password,

Is it there any way to force the system to ask existing password before changing root password?

There were non-tech solutions available but searching for some technical tweak for this problem.

Comment: There are ways to prevent passwd from being used but if you do that you won't be able to change the password yourself.  Why are you running as root despite the mountain of security problems that exists including the problem yourself describe?

Comment: @Ramhound beat me to it... are you crazy to be constantly using root... and to also leave the machine unattended and logged in as root?!

Comment: BigChris and ramhound  friends,i never leave my machine unattended or without locking my account ,just as a preventive measure i wish to do some tweak

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 - I for reasons of keeping my sanity cannot provide an answer to this question.

Comment: If you've got physical access, you can get a screwdriver, remove the harddisk, and put that in another computer. Of course, that fails if you have full disk encryption - but such encryption is exactly the right approach here as well. FDE requires a password and can't be bypassed by physical access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment someone has physical access, breaking into a system is trivial - they could hit you with something as simple as getting into [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) or something fun like [konboot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/).

I could walk up to your system, reboot it, and get in fairly trivially.

However, I'm not the threat here. You are.

Of course running *everything* as root is just... well dumb. Sure there's some things that need root, but if one of the software you run is compromised (or if you fat finger a rm -rf), you don't have your lovely linux permissions to protect you. Heck, some applications have been known to accidentally wipe your whole system

[image]

For starters, stop running kali linux. Start with a *mainstream* distro, and install it from scratch. Set up a proper user with the ability to use sudo and an *encrypted* home directiory. For extra credit, do full disk encryption.

[image]

That should keep folk out better than any bandaid fix you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the feature you describe is considered a *security feature*.

For a normal user, changing a password **does** require providing the current password to be changed, while no such thing exists for root.

The reason is that you may lose your root password, in which case your machine would be well nigh unusable if changing root's password required knowledge of the current password.

Instead, you can boot your machine from a live distro, chroot into your HDD/SSD, change the root password, and then go back to normal use of the machine.

The root account is **not** made for everyday use of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This cannot be done.

The "passwd" command does not ask root for a password.

What you could do, which is not recommended, is to "mv" the passwd to another location (passwd-orig), and make a script file that prompts the user for a password before running "passwd-orig".  However, if a person had access to the command line, and had root-level privileges, they could just run "passwd-orig" directly, thereby thwarting your attempt to secure things that way.

Then, what about the other ways of changing the root's password?  e.g., running "vipw", or editing a text file directly?  The reason I'm saying you cannot do this is that there are too many open holes.  If you try to plug all of them, you're likely to start breaking some other functionality, which is why I'm saying you can't do this.  This is NOT the right way to go about things.

The right way is to stop being "root" all the time.  Instead, start using the "sudo" command.  Preferably, extensively.  e.g., "sudo cp", "sudo nano", etc.  But if that's too much work, you can just "sudo ${SHELL}", and then type "exit" before walking away.  (Just be aware that if you have sudo ask for a password, sudo might remember that you're authenticated, and then not ask for a password for subsequent commands, for some length of time which defaults to 10 minutes.)

Answer (score 1):

> One of the common problem i face was any user whom has physical access can change my root password within minutes .

Physical access while a system is powered on means many other security features are useless.  Devise a way to physically lock it or power off your system when you aren't actually using it.

If you are letting anyone log on to your system as root, stop doing that.  Learn about `sudo` if you wish to delegate the ability to run specific commands as root to other users.

If you continually run your system as root, stop doing that.  Learn about `sudo` which lets you run root commands from a normal account as needed without the danger of being logged in as root all the time.

`passwd` doesn't require an existing password for `root` because `root` is assumed to be used by the administrator of the system and that administrator may need to reset passwords for others.  `root` can just directly modify `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` anyway so it'd be pointless.